# R Corrplot square (tile) size

Tags: r, r-corrplot

I'm plotting a correlation plot with 10 variables using method="number." I'm trying to export the plot with large font sizes (number.cex = 3, tl.cex = 3) for publication purposes, but the squares do not increase in size to accommodate the larger fonts. Is there a way to modify this?

This is my code if it helps:

```
corrplot(as.matrix(K), tl.cex = 3, tl.col = "black", method = "color", 
         outline = T,  order="hclust", 
         addCoef.col = "black", number.digits = 2, number.cex = 3, 
         cl.pos = 'b', cl.cex = 3, addrect = 3, rect.lwd = 3, 
         col = colorRampPalette(c("midnightblue", "white","darkred"))(100))
```

Comment: How big is your matrix K?

Comment: 10x10, it tabulates the pairwise correlation between each of the 10 variables

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should tune the `width`, `height` and `res` parameters of your graphic output file.
See an example below.

```
set.seed(1)
X = matrix(runif(1000),ncol=10)
library(corrplot)
png(file="corr.png", res=300, width=4500, height=4500)
corrplot(as.matrix(cor(X)), tl.cex = 3, tl.col = "black", method = "color", 
         outline = T,  order="hclust", 
         addCoef.col = "black", number.digits = 2, number.cex = 3, 
         cl.pos = 'b', cl.cex = 3, addrect = 3, rect.lwd = 3, 
         col = colorRampPalette(c("midnightblue", "white","darkred"))(100))
dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: POssibly a dumb question....but why is the plot not showing up when using png(file="corr.png", res=300, width=4500, height=4500)....moreover how do I save the plot than?

Comment: Sorry i had to use dev.off()....but still I dont get what the png(file="corr.png", res=300, width=4500, height=4500) does before calling the plot...I dont see how it changes the plot

Comment: @H.berg `png(file="corr.png", res=300, width=4500, height=4500)` redirects the output of the plot command (the graph) into a file in a png format. Try `?Devices`. You can see the list of available graphic devices.

Answer (score 1):

Might be a really stupid idea, but depending on what version of R you use, you could simply go to full screen with the window that pops up once you run your `corrplot()` function. That has worked for me in the past. And then I guess you should make sure to choose the right format; TIFF for instance.

The more sophisticated solution would be [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tiff/tiff.pdf) of course. Here the idea is to adjust the figure parameters once you write it/ save it. Does that make sense?

Generally, the idea is something like this (with interchangable format types):

```
tiff(filename=".tiff",width=...,height=...,res=...)
```

or

```
jpeg()
```

The packages you can try for that are {grDevices} or {tiff} and there are certainly hundreds more. ;)

Let me know if that worked out for you.

Cheers!

Comment: Also, I learned that questions should contain a reproducible example (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)). To me that made sense because it makes it easier for others to respond and for you to get useful advice, right? But I'm myself still learning how this stuff works on stackoverflow ;)